# How does setuptools decide which files to keep for sdist/bdist?

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils

I'm working on a Python package that uses `namespace_packages` and `find_packages()` like so in setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(name="package",
    version="1.3.3.7",
    package=find_packages(),
    namespace_packages=['package'], ...)
```

It isn't in source control because it is a bundle of upstream components. There is no MANIFEST.

When I run `python setup.py sdist` I get a tarball of most of the files under the `package/` directory but any directories that don't contain `.py` files are left out.

What are the default rules for what `setup.py` includes and excludes from built distributions? I've fixed my problem by adding a `MANIFEST.in` with

```
recursive-include package *
```

but I would like to understand what setuptools and distutils are doing by default.

Comment: also see [how-files-are-included-in-an-sdist](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/using-manifest-in/#how-files-are-included-in-an-sdist)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a package_data directive.  For example, if you want to include files with .txt or .rst extensions:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(name="package",
    version="1.3.3.7",
    package=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    namespace_packages=['package'], 
     package_data = {
        # If any package contains *.txt or *.rst files, include them:
        '': ['*.txt', '*.rst']...

)
```

Comment: Ok I did what you sad. But when i instal it by ``pip install git+git://repo`` it does not include files. Are the suppose tu be in curtain level of directory layout?